# SQL Server 2008 R2 : calculate columns of a table based on values of another table

Tags: sql-server

After hours spent in trying to figuring out a solution, I have finally decided to ask for help to experts in SQL Server 2008 R2.

My problem is the following: I have two tables in a database.

The first (`table_a`) has records of all the policies belonging to a certain `customer_id`. They are all yearly policies so each of them has an `inception_date` and an `expiry_date`. As they are term life policies with decreasing amount insured, at each following renewal the amount insured decreases. Some customers have more than one policy and those ones are my target.

The second table (`table_b`) has, for the same `customer_id`, the data about claims (`amount_paid` and `date_of_event` are the columns I am interested in).

Now, I would like to check whether, in case of claim, **ALL** the policies in force at the `date_of_event`, have been correctly taken into consideration and, in case some of those policies have not been considered, to calculate the amount `not paid` (difference between the Sum of all the amount insured in force for a certain `customer_id` at the `date_of_event` of the claim and the amounts actually paid)

The amounts insured in force are the ones connected to all the policies of a customer with

```
inception_date < date_of_event 
and datediff(day, inception_date, date_of_event) < 365
```

I would like to get the total amounts in force at the date of event per customer, the total amount paid for that claim.

I hope I managed to explain clearly my task and I would appreciate very much if somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance

Edit: the data structure is the following:
[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM3A0.jpg)

and this is what I would like to get
[Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKN4U.jpg)

Sorry for having linked pictures, but I am really terrible at formatting

Comment: It's more clear if you add your data structure, sample data and your desired result.

Comment: Added Data structure and expected result @TriV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want calculate data for ***each*** `customerid - eventdate` in `tableB`, try this

```
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT b.CustomerId, b.date_of_event, sum(Amount_Paid) AS Total_Amount_Paid
   FROM tableB b 
   GROUP BY b.CustomerId, b.date_of_event
)
SELECT t.CustomerId,t.date_of_event, sum(a.Amount_Insured) AS Total_Amount_due, t.Total_Amount_Paid
FROM temp t
INNER JOIN table_A a ON a.Customer_Id = t.CustomerId
AND a.inception_date BETWEEN dateadd(year, -1 , t.date_of_event ) AND t.date_of_event
GROUP BY t.CustomerId, t.date_of_event, t.Total_Amount_Paid
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but I have got the following error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'temp.Total_Amount_Paid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. @TriV

Comment: oh, then add `t.Total_Amount_Paid` to group by column

Comment: Marked as solved as it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot